# Find and access app's variable

Tags: android, variables

I am using Beautiful Widgets app on my Android phone and I'd like to use the current temperature as a Tasker variable.

The reason is that I have created a custom UCCW widget and set it to open BW's forecast app - by calling Tasker task, which calls this intent:

```
com.levelup.beautifulwidgets.full.activities.ForecastActivityFull
```

Now that the widget opens BW, I'd like it to show the same temperature as BW - however, UCCW does not offer the same weather data providers as BW, so the temperature values differ, which is lame (e.g. UCCW widget says 5°C and BW says 7°C).

So, is it possible to somehow go through the BW app, find what variables it uses internally, get the value and save it to Tasker variable? (Because, you know, UCCW allows me to add a Tasker variable to the widget, which in this case would be the temperature obtained from BW, so that they would match.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Android Security Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html), Android applications are sandboxed from one another, meaning you cannot view the data/variables that another app is using unless they specifically build an interface (such as a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)) that exposes their internal data to other applications.

Unfortunately, I don't think Beautiful Widget has built any interface to view their weather data nor have published what service they use to get weather information (so you could pull from the same source), although some seem to think that it is The Weather Channel.